# Why would I serialize an object instead of doing a file output?

Tags: java, file, serialization, save, output

I don't currently understand why I would choose to serialize an object instead of just doing a file output and then having a function read that file. What do I gain from serializing an object?

Comment: Arguably these both can be considered serialization. The specifics behind how you persist/reconstruct the state of the object don't really define serialization. For example, one could serialize an object to YAML, or to XML, or to a binary file, but all of them are forms of serialization. It really just depends on how 'human readable'/portable you want the persisted data to be, and how much time you want to spend on the translation logic.

Answer (score 2):

You gain an industry-standard way of reading and writing an object's data, using a W3C approved data exchange format that has almost universal support for readers and writers in almost every programming language.

Comment: Your answer it's better than mine. It deserves to be in first place.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization makes it easy to store the state of objects,
and objects inside them (If they are `Serializable` and not marked as `transient`).

The benefits *in your case* :

Imagine you have a lot of different classes. Maybe coding a custom `File-to-class` parser is harder than `readObject()`

Answer (score 0):

When you `serialize` an `object`, you are copying the actual `byte` data in memory into a `stream`. When you `de-serialize` that stream back into an `object` you get the identical object back including its internal object ID, which you would not get if you had written the properties of the object to a file, and then read it back in and interpreted it.

This means, if you `serialize` a collection of `objects` that `reference` each other, when you `de-serialize` them, they will still maintain their `references` to each other. This is good also for debugging a program. If an exception occurs you can create a memory dump on the users computer, and if they send it to you, then you can see directly what was in memory and the problems that may have been caused.

It is also easier to `serialize` a complex `object` with many properties to a `stream` than it is to build some `string` of representative data, which you will have to be read back, parse and construct a new `object` with it.

Really what you gain, is that it is easier/quicker and better for debugging.